# True / False statement regarding location of roots of the polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, roots

This question was asked in Masters of Mathematics entrance exam of my Institute and I was unable to solve it.

> Suppose p is a polynomial with real coefficients. Then which of the following statements is necessarily true?

2 options have been contradicted by counterexample.

But these 2 options are really confusing me and I can't approach them.

So, which one is true and how can I rigorously prove it.

> C. There is exactly 1 root of the derivative p' between any 2 consecutive roots of p.

> D. There is atleast one root of the derivative  p' between any two consecutive roots of p.

Kindly help.

Comment: For (C) look at the zero polynomial as a counterexample. For (D) think about Rolle's theorem.

Comment: For C you can also think of the graph of a quartic where the middle hump does not cross the x-axis.

Comment: You're only asked for an answer A to D, not a proof.

Comment: (C) fails when you have a root with multiplicity $\ge 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, option $(d)$ is true,

Try with the example, $p=(x-1)^2 (x-3) $

Here, $p'$ have two roots $1,2$ between $1$ and $3$,